# Linkedin API: Cannot get positions for one specific linkedin user

Tags: linkedin-api

We are using Linkedin Api to load information about linkedin users to our product. The thing is, it fails for one specific user.

I would like help with this problem. I have the users linkedin id but I don't know if it's wise to write it herer.

How can Linkedin help me with this?

Best,
Rikard Skelander